# Google App Engine : High CPU Utilization

Tags: google-app-engine, cpu-usage, google-cloud-platform

I have around 5 projects, with simple under construction message on Google App Engine and recently they were suspended with the following reason :

```
Violation of Cloud Platform Terms Of Service
```

When I contact Google team, I got this :

```
XXXX,

Can you provide with a detailed description as 
to what your projects were doing? 

We detected high CPU utilization from each of your projects.

XXXX.
```

Assuming all the pages/content in the application is according to the TOS, can't we use the allotted instance to it's full peak?

I tried finding about the CPU Utilization in their Cloud Platform's TOS. But nothing found.

What are the limitations of using an instance's CPU utilization as per Google's Cloud Platform Terms of Service?

What might be the other reasons, which might lead to the suspension of my Google App Engine project which contains a single under construction page?

These domains has hardly any visits.

Not sure if these logs are saying anything, but some of the logs for my website are as follows :

```
2014-11-25 17:29:48.342 200 1.23 KB 30ms /
192.99.107.208 - - [25/Nov/2014:03:59:48 -0800] 
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1257 - "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; meanpathbot/1.0; +http://www.meanpath.com/meanpathbot.html)" 
"www.sai.rocks" ms=30 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000140 instance=00c61b117ce5cd4a31855df6764c84b074be61 app_engine_release=1.9.16

2014-11-26
2014-11-26 14:46:37.970 200 2.63 KB 212ms /
54.146.190.175 - - [26/Nov/2014:01:16:37 -0800] 
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2691 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3)" 
"sai.rocks" ms=212 cpu_ms=93 cpm_usd=0.000301 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117ca07c5404865802f60f07f42379a8 app_engine_release=1.9.16
14:46:37.968 
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

2014-11-27
2014-11-27 17:31:17.131 200 1.23 KB 16ms /robots.txt
66.249.69.204 - - [27/Nov/2014:04:01:17 -0800] 
"GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 1257 - "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" 
"sasidhar.sai.rocks" ms=16 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000140 instance=00c61b117ca07c5404865802f60f07f42379a8 app_engine_release=1.9.16
2014-11-27 17:31:17.358 200 1.23 KB 73ms /
66.249.69.172 - - [27/Nov/2014:04:01:17 -0800] 
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1257 - "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" 
"sasidhar.sai.rocks" ms=73 cpu_ms=23 cpm_usd=0.000140 instance=00c61b117ca07c5404865802f60f07f42379a8 app_engine_release=1.9.16

2014-11-28
2014-11-28 00:38:30.805 200 1.23 KB 49ms /
66.249.69.56 - - [27/Nov/2014:11:08:30 -0800] 
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1257 - "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" 
"sasidhar.sai.rocks" ms=49 cpu_ms=47 cpm_usd=0.000140 instance=00c61b117ca07c5404865802f60f07f42379a8 app_engine_release=1.9.16
```

**Edit**

Utilization Graph : [Utilization Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBt90.png)

Comment: What does your utilization graph show (on the App Engine console > Dashboard)?

Comment: Added Utilization Graph for last 30 days and it is absolute flat at x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replied for the above mail (added in the question) with the following

```
Hi xxxx,

Thanks for the details.

All of the 5 projects that were suspended have just one single 
static page with Google Analytics using Google Tag Manager. 
And nothing else.

My suspended projects are : 
xxx-xxxxxxx-xx, xxx-xxxxxxx-xx, xxx-xxxxxxx-xx, xxx-xxxxxxx-xx, 
xxx-xxxxxxx-xx

In fact all the 21 projects that I have contain one and only one 
single static page as said above. Not a single other file.

I didn't get any notification mail regarding this incident 
(High CPU Utilization) for any of the above suspended projects.

Could you please elaborate on High CPU Utilization? Is this 
on number of requests per second? or a single process taking 
entire CPU and stopping other requests to process? or 
something else?

Let me know if you need anything from my side 

Thanks,
XXXXXXXXX.
```

For this I got a reply from Google, not mentioning any reason for suspending my accounts and they simply un-suspended all my projects.

This is the reply I got

```
Hi xxxxxx,

I have reinstated your projects. Please give it a few minutes for 
the effect to propagate.

Thanks,
XXXXXXX.
```

Not sure what happened. But they un-suspeneded my projects.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to follow the link https://cloud.google.com/terms/ and look for Suspension and Removals in the document. They explicitly mentioned 2 points which leads to application suspension.

Comment: I checked all those terms and found all my five projects are according to their terms with a single static page, with very few or zero hits.